# how to store invoices with different number of products in it, in a single table using SQL

Tags: c#, sql, invoice, inventory-management

I am creating an Inventory management system using C# in Visual studio and the database is SQL. The thing I want is that, how can I store Invoices which I generated while billing, as these bills have different numbers of products. The question is how can I store these bills' details in a single table with invoice number as a primary key. Anybody can help me with this?

Comment: You should have two tables, for invoices and for invoice lines. You can have only the invoice lines table, but then you will have to duplicate the invoice information across all lines that belong to the same invoice, make sure that it is always the same across these lines, and cannot have the invoice id as a primary key.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store `invoices` in *one* table, then you would probably represent the repeated data as JSON data structures.

I do not recommend that approach.  You probably want two tables (at least):

- `invoices`
- `invoiceLines`

The first would have an `invoiceId` and one row per *invoice*.  The second would have one row per "product" (or whatever) on the invoice.  It would have a foreign key relationship to `invoiceId`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to store the Invoice and InvoiceLines (Products) in a single table then you need a column to store serialized version of the list of products.

The following link will help:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1166099/Entity-Framework-Storing-complex-properties-as-JSO

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should work on data modeling techniques used to store this kind of data. In your case, I would suggest creating two different table

1. Invoice table (or Order table): The main table that will store information like Invoice date, Invoice ID, CustomerID, Purchase Amount, etc
2. Invoice Details table ( or order items table): Store the order items for the Invoice ID, Product ID ( Product that was purchased, you can create another table for products as well if you require ), Quantity, price, etc.